# Help with '98 Civic EXI engine swap: d15z4 to d16a7

Tags: honda

Well, I equipped my '98 honda civic exi with a motor d16a7 SOHC 16V (not VTEC) instead of the d15z4 engine SOHC 16v , where I would like to know what type (reference) calculator (ECU?) that goes with this engine because with the old calculator installed it displaces gasoline through the exhaust manifold and the engine does not start.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Welcome on this site, please edit your original question, most likely this question will get closed. I am sure people are willing to help you, but you need to rewrite your question so they can understand it.

Comment: Are you asking for help in selecting an ECU (engine control unit) to go with the new engine? That's my best guess as to what you mean by the "calculator."

Comment: @Myself if there's actually a duplicate, please flag this one as the duplicate and refer to the other.